# Can I use the same command to checkout a tag/branch as a branch?

Tags: git

I want to write a bash function that checkouts a tag/branch as a branch with that name. Is there a way to do that?

I tried the following but it works only for tags and not for branches.:

```
git checkout -b {1} {2}
```

Here is what I see:

```
$ git checkout -b v1.0 v1.0  # works
$ git checkout -b release release  # fails
[ fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'release' at the same time. ]
$ git checkout -b release origin/release  # works if i prefix origin
$ git checkout release  # works if i don't give anything
```

Can I combine this into a single command?

Comment: What do you intend to do by `git checkout -b release release`? Why can't you just run `git checkout release`?

Comment: You want to copy a branch? Or just checkout it? To checkout don't use `-b`

Comment: @mkrieger, The reason is that it will checkout in a headless state for a tag. I didn't want that?

Comment: [`git checkout -b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt) creates a new branch before checking it out. It, of course, fails if a branch with the same name already exists.

Comment: Worth mentioning: if `release` is a tag, and you create a *branch* name `release` and then use that branch to make new commits, you create yourself a sad repository: `git checkout release` gets you the *branch* (or tip commit thereof), but other Git operations using the name `release` get you the *tag* (the commit identified by the tag, which no longer matches the tip commit of the branch). Working in such a repository is confusing and error-prone. In short, that's not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @torek, I meant `release` to be some branch which I wanted to checkout. `release` is not the actual name of any of my branch or tag :)

Comment: Understood, but the point is that there really are two OK cases: (1) There's no branch name, so use `git checkout -b` to create one, which works. (2) There *is* a branch name, so use `git checkout` to switch to it, which also works. Then there's no need for tricky use of `-B`, you just use `git checkout` and if it fails, `git checkout -b`. The `-B` trick in the answer you accepted only works if there's an *existing* name (branch or tag name) and if it's unwise to *create a new branch name* when the existing name is a *tag* name, you probably should not use `-B` here at all.

Comment: Ok @torek, I could do a failure check on`git checkout` and do `git checkout -b` if needed. Can you consolidate this as an answer? I will accept it. I was wondering if there is a *single* command for all this but that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-B`—the method described in [mkrieger1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54823212/1256452)—does work, but in general this isn't a great idea.  It leads to a problem case if we create a *branch* name that shadows a *tag* name.

It's probably wisest, in cases like this, to check for various error conditions first.  If those error conditions exist, stop and get help from some human.  Proceed only if all is well.  Here, the *proceed if all is well* case occurs when the branch name already exists as a branch name and you can switch to it, or when there is no branch name but there is a known starting point that uses some *other* name, and you can create the branch and switch to it.

In other words, you probably should allow `git checkout existing-branch` and `git checkout -b new-branch start-point`.  Here, *`existing-branch`* should *require* that the name be a *branch* name.  Similarly, the *`new-branch`* variant should *require* that *`start-point`* be a *different* name than *`new-branch`* and that *`new-branch`* not be an existing valid tag or other name.  Allowing / requiring these requires a little bit of if/else style logic.

#### Background

Suppose you have some short-name string *S*, where *S* might be `release` or `dev` or `v1.2` or whatever it may be (we might presume that *S* is not a raw hash ID, though we can actually test this).  Given this *S* and a repository, there are—at least for this particular problem—two cases to consider:

1. `git rev-parse S` produces some hash ID.  *S* is probably an existing name.  It could be a branch name, so that *S* is short for `refs/heads/S`, or a tag name, so that *S* is short for `refs/tags/S`:

   ```
   $ git rev-parse stash-exp
   8dbdf339cd2e757143d9f222f662edd8ef745ea8
   ```

   So here, `stash-exp` is probably a branch or tag.
2. Or, `git rev-parse S` *does not* produce some hash ID, but instead fails:

   ```
   $ git rev-parse gronk
   gronk
   fatal: ambiguous argument 'gronk': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
   'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
   ```

This particular usage of `git rev-parse` winds up printing the name itself to stdout, and the `fatal` message above to stderr (which you can test for yourself by redirecting stdout and stderr to two different files).  Adding `--verify` changes it to just complain (and exit nonzero = failure):

```
$ git rev-parse --verify gronk && echo ok || echo failed
fatal: Needed a single revision
failed
```

while `git rev-parse --verify stash-exp` continues to work (and exit 0 = success):

```
$ git rev-parse --verify stash-exp && echo ok || echo failed
8dbdf339cd2e757143d9f222f662edd8ef745ea8
ok
```

Note that we can instead have `git rev-parse` tell us the *full name* of the reference, or fail:

```
$ git rev-parse --verify --symbolic-full-name stash-exp
refs/heads/stash-exp
$ git rev-parse --verify --symbolic-full-name gronk
fatal: Needed a single revision
```

From this, we can see that `stash-exp` is in fact a *branch* name.  Meanwhile `v2.1.0` is a *tag name*:

```
$ git rev-parse --verify --symbolic-full-name v2.1.0
refs/tags/v2.1.0
```

It's worth noting here that there are more cases where `git rev-parse` can turn a name into a hash-ID, and that not all of these are symbolic references.  [The gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) has the full list of what names work, including things like relative operations: `HEAD~3`, `master^2~2`, and so on.  Using `--symbolic-full-name` allows us to have `git rev-parse` tell us the *full* name, which we can then match against the pattern or patterns we care about:

```
# check whether $name is a branch name
hash=$(git rev-parse --verify "$name" 2>/dev/null) || {
    echo "I do not recognize $name at all" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
fullname=$(git rev-parse --verify --symbolic-full-name "$name" 2>/dev/null) || {
    echo "I can translate $name to $hash but it is not any branch or tag name" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
case "$fullname" in
refs/heads/*) ;; # ok - it is a branch name
*)  echo "$name is really $fullname and that is not a branch" 1>&2
    exit 1;;
esac
```

So the above code fragment verifies that `$name` is set to an existing branch name.  It computes its current tip commit hash ID, saved in `$hash`, and its full name, which is going to be `refs/heads/$name` due to the rev-parse rules, and which is saved in `$fullname`.

#### Why do we care?

Well, one reason to care is that `git checkout` behaves differently with branch vs tag names:

```
$ git checkout stash-exp
Switched to branch 'stash-exp'
```

Since `stash-exp` is a branch, we're *on* it.

```
$ git checkout v2.1.0
Note: checking out 'v2.1.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. ... [massive snip]
```

Since `v2.1.0` is *not* a branch, we're on *no* branch now.  Git has instead switched to this detached HEAD mode.

```
$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 6c4ab27f23 Git 2.1
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

Now we're back on `master`, which *is* a branch.  So it matters, potentially a lot, whether we give `git checkout` a branch name.

#### Why we care even more

Let's use `git checkout -b` now to create a *branch* name that is the *same* short name *S* as our *tag* name `v2.1.0`:

```
$ git checkout -b v2.1.0 v2.1.0
Switched to a new branch 'v2.1.0'
$ git rev-parse v2.1.0
warning: refname 'v2.1.0' is ambiguous.
7452b4b5786778d5d87f5c90a94fab8936502e20
```

Hm, this **ambiguous** thing is new, isn't it?  Let's create a new dummy commit:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m dummy
[v2.1.0 83429187cf] dummy
$ git show | sed 's/@/ /'
commit 83429187cfe0ff9055453b8c2284deabb21139aa (HEAD -> v2.1.0)
Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 23 11:44:29 2019 -0800

    dummy
$
```

So the tip commit of our branch is this new commit, `83429187...`.

But:

```
$ git show v2.1.0 | sed -e 's/@/ /' -e 10q
warning: refname 'v2.1.0' is ambiguous.
tag v2.1.0
Tagger: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 15 15:09:28 2014 -0700

Git 2.1
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)

iQIcBAABAgAGBQJT7oUZAAoJELC16IaWr+bLD3UP/iqk7c+1BdEjIUks3JS8eUu7
V/sU1dS2K/8ZeeQa9aeqmAxt/9aqeF6DNtN9AcAO5bf2WeGYfKkTdxsb4eWAaw+W
$
```

**The name `v2.1.0` sometimes means the *tag*, and sometimes means the *branch*.  That's what this "ambiguous" warning is about.**  If you go back to [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) I linked-to earlier, you'll see that there is a six-step process for resolving a symbolic name *S* to a hash ID.  The step that uses the *tag* name comes before the step that uses the *branch* name.

**What this means is that, in effect, a big chunk of Git prefers tags to branches.**  The exception is with commands that *know or assume* their argument is a *branch* name, such as `git checkout` and `git branch`.  But what this in turn means is that if you create the ambiguous-name situation, you get yourself in trouble.

Let's switch back to `master` and delete this not-very-good branch name:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
$ git branch -D v2.1.0
Deleted branch v2.1.0 (was 83429187cf).
```

#### This is why `git checkout -B release release` is not a good plan

For `git checkout -B release release` to work, `release` must be a valid symbolic name for a commit.  That is, `git rev-parse release` must work (and in fact, `git rev-parse release^{commit}` must work, though we don't need to get into that particular detail here).

If *S* (standing for `release` or `stash-exp` or whatever) is a valid symbolic name, then one possibility is that *S* is an existing branch name.  But if that's the case, the operation of `git checkout -B S S` is to set *S* to the value already in *S*.  This is harmless, but also pointless: *S* was already a branch name and we could have just run `git checkout S`.

If it's a valid symbolic name, so that it can *become* a branch name, but *is not now* a branch name, it's probably a *tag* name.  In this case `git checkout -B S S` will create *S* as a new branch name.  We could have used `git checkout -b S S` here too, because *S* isn't *yet* a branch name, and as we saw with `v2.1.0` above, the lowercase `-b` option works.  But this leads to the **warning: refname 'v2.1.0' is ambiguous** situation: now we have both a branch *and* a tag.  If we think this is a bad idea—and *I* at least think so—then we should not be doing this at all.

The conclusion here is that we should be using `git checkout` with an *existing* branch name, to switch *to* it, or else we should be using `git checkout -b new-branch start-point`, with a *new* branch name, that is not already in use in any other form, so that `git rev-parse --verify` says *I don't know that name*.  The *`start-point`* tells Git what commit to use to *start* the new branch, and since that has to be something that resolves to an actual commit hash, it *cannot* be the same as the new branch name: we know for sure that the new name does not resolve to anything at all.

Comment: I will use the `if/else` checks in that case. Thanks a lot for clarifying the details.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $ git checkout -b release release
> ```

This means: Create a new branch `release` at the commit specified by `release`. Since a branch called `release` must already exist for this to work, it cannot be created and the command fails.

From the documentation of *git-checkout*:

> ```
> git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]
> ```
>
> Specifying *-b* causes a new branch to be created as if *git-branch(1)* were called and then checked out. […]
>
> If *-B* is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of
>
> ```
> $ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
> $ git checkout <branch>
> ```
>
> that is to say, the branch is not reset/created unless "git checkout" is successful.

So you could try using `-B` instead of `-b`.